# ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/charts/be.js' in '/vercel/workpath0/my-app/pages'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have stumbled in deploying my next.js app through vercel.
It works completely well in local using command 'npm run dev'.
But when I tried to deploy it through vercel with Github remote repository, it throws error like below

```
18:07:58.299    Failed to compile.
18:07:58.299    ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/charts/be.js' in '/vercel/workpath0/my-app/pages'
18:07:58.299    > Build error occurred
18:07:58.300    Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
18:07:58.300        at /vercel/workpath0/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918
18:07:58.300        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
18:07:58.300        at async /vercel/workpath0/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:1:525
```

My `be.js` component never used any server side methods or modules but only a library using in client side.

```js
import { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Treemap, Tooltip } from 'recharts';

// some internal code

export default class BE extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : this.props.data
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Treemap
                width={500}
                height={300}
                data={this.state.data}
                dataKey="size"
                ratio={4 / 3}
                stroke="#fff"
                fill="#8884d8"
                content={<CustomizedContent colors={COLORS} />}
                style={{marginTop:50}}
            >
                <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>}/>
            </Treemap>
        );
      }
}
```

And also in `index.js` which imports the `be.js` component, using proper path for it and not omitting `.js` extension, too.
I changed all the components` name to lower case just in case error occurs regarding Case.

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import fs from 'fs';
import Layout from '../components/layout.js';
import modifyData from '../lib/data_modifier.js'

import BE from '../components/charts/be.js';
// there are more imported components


export default function Home({ data }) {
  // internal code. no error
}
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const rawData = fs.readFileSync('./dataset/test.json');
  const data = modifyData(JSON.parse(rawData));
  return {
    props: {
      data
    }
  }
}
```

My app is only a simple single page, and configs are pretty simple as well. Just in case you should look through my version of dependencies, I attach it below.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "next": "^10.0.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5"
  }
}
```

I used 'fs' module only inside of `getStaticProps()` in `index.js`.

Comment: Do you get any errors when running `npm run build` locally?

Comment: No, it works fine when running `npm run build`. Frankly speaking, I didn't know the command so that I implemented it for the first time. Anyway, there wasn't any error, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your remote branch may not be updated with the new names after you change to lower case because the name not changed, only lower case characters. In Vercel and other server that use Linux will show the ModuleNotFoundError, because in Linux the same folder or file with lower case and Upper case are different.

Fix the names in the remote branch to fix error.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this same issue. So basically, I used wrong way of importing my layout component. I wrote `import Layout from 'path-to-component/layout'` but I had `export default function Layout()...` in my Layout component.
My fix:

1. Make sure you are exporting and importing the right files
2. Run `git rm -r --cached .` this command will remove all cached files in your git.
3. After removing all cached files, we need to add all our files to git again with the updates. So run `git add --all .`
4. Run `git commit -m "commit message here!!!"`
5. Run `git push origin 'github branch name'`, to push code to github

Answer (score 0):

**I had a similar problem with my first deployment.**

I tried to change the component name, `import path (full with .js)`, different providers, etc...

The only thing that helped me was deleting Git Repository and pushing a new one from Visual Studio Code. After that, the build was a success on both Vercel and DigitalOcean.